# Hooking Commands (runtime, source, echo, echom, echoerr) in Vim

Tags: vim, hook, autocmd

I'm working on a vim 'logging' plugin. I'm attempting to hook any calls to 'source', 'echo', 'echom', 'echoerr'. AFAIK, the way that you *typically* execute arbitrary code on 'events' is through the use of an autocmd(grp) with an autocmd-event - however it doesn't appear to be possible to hook any of the those commands through this method.

Any suggestions how else this might be possible?

Edit:

I'm currently playing around with this a little and shoved what I'm working on into a gist here:

- https://gist.github.com/nfarrar/951c0c5a8908430132d6

Answer (score 0):

There is the `SourcePre` event that allows you to hook into scripts.

You can access past messages via

```
:redir => var
:silent messages
:redir END
```

maybe periodically on the `CursorHold` event.

But please carefully reconsider the need for a "logging plugin". I think this is best done in core Vim, not Vimscript, and Vim already provides quite good logging infrastructure (cp. `'verbose'` and `'verbosefile'`). And there are plugins like DrChip's *Decho* for instrumenting your Vimscript code.

Comment: Thank you - I am taking your advice and currently exploring some builtin or already built options.